# Get ComboBox Selected Item

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TUserDS}" x:Name="UserCB" 
SelectionChanged="UserCB_SelectionChanged" Width="200" 
HorizontalAlignment="left" SelectedIndex="0" Padding="2" Margin="0 10 0 0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UserName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadUserCB();
        }

        private void loadUserCB()
        {
            SqlDbConnect sdc = new SqlDbConnect();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sdc.SqlQuery("select * from TUser");
            ds=sdc.QueryEx("TUserDS");
            UserCB.DataContext = ds;

            string selUserName = UserCB.SelectedItem.ToString(); //this code failed to get the selected item

        }
    }
}
```

in MainWindow.xaml I created a combobox, then in MainWindow.xaml.cs I bind the combobox with a table from Sqlserver.
How can I get the selected item from UserCB combobox?

Comment: Have you tried `string selUserName = UserCB.SelectedValue;`? If The text and value are the same then you can also do `string selUserName = UserCB.Text;`

Comment: Yes I did, but SelectedValue also returned null

Comment: I could,however, set UserCB.SelectedIndex=3 or any number to select the user that I want. But I don't know how to get the string of the selected Item.

Comment: The design pattern you are using is obsolete. you can learn about MVVM.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [DisplayMemberPath](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/displaymemberpath/)

Comment: @Bizhan yeah, MVVM is a nice solution for him. Hard coding to updating the relevant properties in DataContextChanged is too much trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to use MVVM framework.

Since Binding is based on notify rather than active, in the case of non-MVVM framework, if modify DataContext directly. All has bound property won't know that the DataContext has been updated, so they're value won't change.

By the MVVM framework, using the ViewModel that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface will notify all related binding properties when the property changed, avoiding the problem of DataContext updating.

Simple example:

```
//C# Code
//Define a ViewModel
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataSet _ds;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public DataSet Ds
    {
        get => _ds;
        set
        {
            _ds = value;
            //Notify: Property "Ds" updated
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Ds"));
        }
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = new VM();
    //set viewmodel to DataContext before InitializeComponent
    InitializeComponent();

    loadUserCB();
}
```

---

```
<!--Xaml Code-->
<!--                            V Note here.*-->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[TUserDS]}" 
          x:Name="UserCB" 
          SelectionChanged="UserCB_SelectionChanged" 
          Width="200" 
          HorizontalAlignment="left"
          SelectedIndex="0" 
          Padding="2"
          Margin="0 10 0 0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

*: DataSet does not support indexer, but the "DataSet.Tables" support indexer.

Because of ComboBox.ItemsSource received VM.Ds Property changed notification, so it will try to update its own data

Comment: I tried setting the SelectedIndex after 'UserCB.DataContext=ds' but even after that the SelectedItem still returned null

Comment: I learned about MVVM after reading your answer and have been using it conveniently until now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your current design then try changing your Xaml to

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TUserDS}" x:Name="UserCB" SelectionChanged="UserCB_SelectionChanged" Width="200" 
HorizontalAlignment="left" SelectedIndex="0"  Padding="2" Margin="0 10 0 0"
DisplayMemberPath="UserName"/>
```

More info [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you have the name ComboBox -> `UserCB`

In class `MainWindow`:

- use a reference `UserCB.SelectedItem` in any method
- use a reference `UserCB.SelectedIndex` when you want to get the item index. In the case of small lists, you can download the index in this way and on this basis read the value from the collection or database of items

(When you call a function with this content, you will get the current value)